# How to check the size of request (upload content) in Chrome dev tool

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am maintaining a legacy Cordova mobile app. The app allows user to send a really big amount of data in ajax. I would like to measure the bottleneck of the request size in some low spec mobile device.

Is there a way to check in Chrome dev tool to see the request size?

It seems in the network tab there is info about the size and  payload of the response only.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can see the Request Headers in the Network tab. They appear below the Response Headers, so they can easily be missed.

**Example:**
Upload of an IPA file to Google Drive.

[image: Request]
You can also see this information in JSON format if you save the Network data to a HAR file:

[image: HAR]

Comment: This answer is not 100% matched my question but It has value to solve mine. for ajax request there is a content-length param in header of the request. Ref for ajax https://monosnap.com/file/urUIpfZuc4hgxqzaxQ5SDcTLKO0fHh#

Comment: @GideonPyzer sometimes, content-length header is not being sent.